# Dynamics CRM deployment: manage solution components dependencies

Tags: dynamics-crm

We are trying to create Dynamics CRM solutions (Online version), following some of the guidelines from [microsoft - ALM best practices](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39044). One of the recommendations is to create a core entities solution and make a managed layer and features on top as separate solutions.

When we create an entity like 'account feedback' - which depends on account - it perfectly fits into the layer. However, if we want to list all the feedback in account form as a subgrid then we are building a dependency from account -> Account Feedback. This forces us to move account feedback feature to the core solution. If this continues, and we build more and more dependencies between the entities we end up moving everything into one big single solution.

What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: You might get more help over at programmers.stackexchange.com as they are more for conceptual design questions like this.

Comment: Thanks. I will post it there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. Just accept that e.g. entity Account might be part of your core.

The core solution will normally contain a big part of your data model and the web resources that are required by its entities are a necessary part of that solution as well.

I recommend to deploy your core solution containing entities *unmanaged* only. Other solution, containing workflows, plugin assemblies and steps etc. can be deployed separately in *managed* solutions.

At a certain level you may find it useful to split your entity model into separate solutions. When you do that you can either distribute the same core entities over these solutions or decide to add your core entities to a base solution.

In the second scenario installation of the base solution is a requirement for successful installation of the other solutions.

Comment: That makes all the entities in my instance go to core and rest of the customization features go to a new package. Wouldn't the unmanaged entities be an issue for upgrades?

Comment: Unmanaged give you more flexibility. Managed solutions were originally designed with ISV add-ons in mind. A requirement for add-ons was the ability to uninstall them without leaving any traces behind. For your company data model extensions this is rather a disadvantage, because an uninstall of a managed solution may as well drop the tables that are part of it and destroy the data in it. Also, when somehow unmanaged modifications to managed entities find their way to your production system, managed updates to the same entities cannot be imported anymore.